# Is there a name for the verbs that can precede other verbs?

Tags: verbs

What are the names of the these following verbs in bold?

I **want** to eat food
I **have** to buy shoes
I **like** to know things
I **need** to find love

They are all verbs that, as far as I can tell, can precede other verbs and make complete sense.

Comment: They are called _catenative verbs_. Here are some examples: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-catenative.php

Comment: _Catenative verb_ just means 'verb that can take a clausal object'.  And not all of the examples you give would be called 'catenative' even by those who use the term -- _have to_ in _I have to buy shoes_ is a fixed phrase and not a combined verb.  Most abstract verbs (which is most verbs) will fit this pattern. The discussion at English Club is useless, since it doesn't explain why, and gives the impression there's only one pattern, when there are dozens.

Comment: @John Lawler. Agreed on "have to". The _English Dictionary of English Grammar_ (Bas Aarts) defines a catenative verb as a "_verb that forms a chain with one or more subsequent verbs_". The English Club page has four patterns. Could you suggest a resource which lists some of the other patterns.

Comment: I would not assume that the definition referred to an actual set of real verbs, instead of a figment of some teacher's imagination. I'm sure Bas has a definition of _chain_ to go with that, since the phrase is as question-begging as _catenative verb_. Since predicate adjectives and nouns can have complements, one wonders if there are catenative adjectives and nouns, too. And I'm not interested in what the English Club has to say. Why are they involved (aside from being free)?

Comment: There are things called "serial verbs", like _go eat_ and _come sit by me_.  They're all idiomatic constructions in English, but many languages have productive systems where one can say the equivalent of _Bill went cut stacked carted the wood home._

Comment: On the many languages point, this question actually came around due to my learning Spanish. In Spanish the infinitive after the verb (I want to eat -> Yo quiero comer) is somewhat more obvious due to the conjugations of the verb and the fact that it isn't my 1st language and taking things for granted.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the the term given in the comments the arrangement of verbs shown is referred to as a (verbal) construction or pattern, called "*verb + to-infinitive*" ([ref.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing)), or sometimes "*verb + infinitive*". This latter way to refer to it still permits to distinguish it from the construction where the verb follows without "to", as then this pattern is referred to as "*verb + infinitive without "to"* or "*verb + bare infinitive*". (There is but a few of these verbs, the most important ones being the modals; the use of the infinitive without "to" is characteristic of every instance of  use of  modals. ([ref.](https://www.englishgrammar.org/infinitives/)))